# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of undefined at VueComponent.onResize

Tags: vue.js

```html
<div ref="controls" class="varie controls"> 
  <div class="control" v-if="spin!='">
    <span>Saved datee</span><span>{{ }}</span>
  </div> 
  <button v-on:click="apply()">Aopply</button>
</div>
```

```
          onResize: function() {
              this.windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
              this.controlsHeight = this.$refs.controls.offsetHeight;
            }
```

Getting the error from these lines of code. How its possible to rectify the issue in Vue js?

Comment: Can you add the full code for the Vue component? Odds are you either have multiple elements with a ref named `controls` or you have none.

Comment: <div ref="controls" class="varie controls">
            <div class="control" v-if="spin!='">
                <span>Saved datee</span><span>{{ }}</span>
            </div>
            <button v-on:click="apply()">Aopply</button>
        </div>

Comment: Is that the entire contents of the `template` for your Vue file?

Comment: no ...but here only i called the ref - controls

Comment: Ok, and the `onResize` function - is this in your `methods` block?

Comment: yes....this onResize is mentioned inside the method block

Comment: At this point, I'd need to see the full file or a minimal, reproducible example to help further:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: where and when is `onResize` called?

Answer (score 0):

this.$refs.controls is getting undefined, please debug this, thats the problem, i cant help you moore without the fully template or component. Regards